# Handling multiple Ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing an application which requires multiple ajax requests, such that `Option2` will be only available when `Button2` will be clicked and its response returned. Similarly, `Option3` will be available only when `Button3` has been clicked. Following is the general structure of the code. I'm building the app in `php` & `mysql`.

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "url-1",
        data: { id: //some-id },
        success: function(response) {
            $('.menu-right').html(response);
            $(".button2").click(function() { //button2 is created when the above response is printed as html
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:  "url-2",
                    data: { id: this.id },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('.menu-right-jump').html(response);
                        $('.button3').click(function() { ////button3 is created when the above response is printed as html
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:  "url-3",
                                data: { id: this.id },
                                success: function(response) {
                                // some things to do
                                },
                                error: function(error) {
                                    alert("Error");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

Currently, everything works. The application will be for a maximum of 10,000 users. I just wanted to know if there was any way better of doing this/or any frameworks available that I can incorporate.

Also: What may be the problems that may arise using this way and ways to clear out those problems.

Comment: That is extremely ugly code...why can't you encapsulate those ajax requests into individual functions?

Comment: @BradM: I'm just a beginner. I just look at free tutorials and then try to get things done. Could you please post an example of encapsulating them as individual functions?

Answer (score 1):

There is a cleaner way of doing it, with jQuery. Using the [`.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "url-1",
        data: { id: //some-id },
        success: function(response) {
            $('.menu-right').html(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});

//When I'm ready... provide a click event
$(".button2").ready(function(){
    $(".button2").click(function() { //button2 is created when the above response is printed as html
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "url-2",
            data: { id: this.id },
            success: function(response) {
                $('.menu-right-jump').html(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
$(".button2").ready(function(){
    $('.button3').click(function() { ////button3 is created when the above response is printed as html
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "url-3",
            data: { id: this.id },
            success: function(response) {
                // some things to do
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problems that arrive doing it your way. Due too much [`nesting`](http://thesassway.com/beginner/the-inception-rule) (For instance, if you need to add 4 more buttons) it could lead too.. technical debt which is much harder to maintain.

> Avoid creating deeply nested if-then statements since they are harder to read and error-prone to maintain. [source](http://coding.tocea.com/tools/pmd/avoiddeeplynestedifstmts/#)

You could go further with this, and better encapsulate each ajax request into a singular function and write your own [`jQuery callback`](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/).

Comment: I didn't know .ready worked like that for arbitrary objects that don't exist yet.  I'll have to try it out.

Comment: Could be recommended instead of using `.html()` to use `.append()` and wrap your `HTML` as `jQuery`, this will allow `jQuery` to better detect the new elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use jquery's `.on` functionality to not have to nest those

```
$('body').on('click' ,'.button2', doButton2request);
$('body').on('click' ,'.button3', doButton3request);

$("#button1").click(doButton1request)

function doButton1request()
{
    do ajax and on success put in the new button
}

function doButton2request()
{
   do ajax and on success put in the new button
}

function doButton3request()
{
   do ajax and on success do "some things to do"
}
```

the on function wires up the event so that whenever anybody clicks on anything (within 'body'), if the class is .button2 for example, it calls the function with that (this) being the item matched.  you you can add and remove the button or the .button2 class as needed.  also with .off you can temporarily stop those events from firing.

So the general idea is, whenever you have clickable items that won't exist at the beginning of the app, you can set up an .on event.   Or, you can have items that don't receive clicks until they have another class added, like ".active"  or something.